# Enter age javascript error

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this specific code and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

```
<script language=javascript type="text/javascript">  
toDays(21);
function toDays(years)
{
    var time;
    time = 365*years;
    return time;
}       
document.write("My age is " + time); 
</script>
```

Comment: `time` has function scope. It can't be accessed outside of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Document.write should be inside function or toDays(21) outside function

```
   function toDays(years)
    {
        var time;
        time = 365*years;
        document.write("My age is " + time); 
        return time;
    } 
document.write("My age is " + toDays(21));
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/oLaRdw

Answer (score 1):

The return value from the function was not stored in a variable.

- Due to hoisting of the function in Javascript, the `toDays` is defined before its defination line.
- Store the result from the function in a global variable `time`.
- Use `document.write` to print the results.

```js
var time = toDays(21);
function toDays(years)
{
    var time;
    time = 365*years;
    return time;
}       
document.write("My age is " + time);
```

Comment: @bloggincodin let me know if you any further confusion.